# Google smart home test suit fail

Tags: google-smart-home

when I tested "Query after xxxxx" case in smart home test suite, I got below error.
Actually, I already implemented Report state and Query.
I don't know why it is and what it's means.

//State 'online' is in queried states but not in reported states: expected false to be true//

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnHNo.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your action in the Test Suite it needs to report state to the Home Graph after every execution. Those states are then compared to the results returned from the QUERY intent. The attached image suggests that `online:true` is missing from the report state response. Please visit [Report State Documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) for more information.